# Object::connect: No such signal MyThread::MySignal()

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qthread

1. My program has one thread class.
2. The **signal** and the **slot** both are in that thread class itself.
3. The header file and the source file are separate.
4. **main ()** function is in the source file itself.

In **main ()**, I am using **connect** as follows:

```
MyThread objA;
Object :: connect (&objA, SIGNAL(MySignal()), &objA, SLOT(MySlot()));
```

**.pro** file is:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Thu Dec 1 13:05:43 2011
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += qtWheel.h
SOURCES += qtWheel.cpp
```

I saw the above error during run time. Please guide.

Comment: can you show your MyThread class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:
The **parameters** of **signal** and **slot** functions were **mismatching**! As soon as I fixed them, the slot got called.

Thanks to: http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the MySignal() and MySlot() as signal & slot in the header file of your MyThread class:

```
class MyThread
{
public:
    MyThread();
signals:
    void MySignal();
public slots:
    void MySlot();
}
```

Comment: Tim and @LwinHtooKo .Thanks to both of you for the reply. It was a dumb fault of mine that I have found. It was a parameter mismatch.